# Calling a specific variable inside of a dictionary and changing its value in an if statement

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I'm struggling to find a way where I can change one value inside a small dictionary without breaking syntax. Relatively new to python, so I just learned about dictionary to save me some grief from having to print the products line by line, would love some help. Right now, it looks like this:

```
products={
    "product 1" : 100,
    "product 2" : 100,
    "product 3" : 100,
    "product 4" : 100,
    "product 5" : 100
}
print("current stock: ",products)

change=input("Would you like to change stock amount? ")

**if "yes" in change.lower():
    chosen_product=input("Which product would you like to change? ")
    change_type=input("Would you like to add or subtract stock? ")**
else:
    print("current stock: ",products)
```

The lines in bold are where I'm struggling to continue.

I can't call the entire product dictionary since I'm having the user choose one product to change, and I have to somehow pull that one product out of the dictionary and change its value, and I also can't put chosen_product in square brackets since that by itself isn't a dictionary.

Comment: Setting a value in a dict is one of the most basic things you can do with it. If you don't know how, then what you need is a good, well structured tutorial - see for example the official one that is part of the official documentation. Stack Overflow is not meant to replace that. If your question is something else, please clarify.

Comment: What do you expect the user to type in the input? I think `chosen_product` will be something like "product 3", but what about for `change_type`?

Comment: change_type should probably be changed to operation just for better understanding, trying to get the user to input whether they want to add or subtract from the original stock value.

Answer (score 0):

```
products={
    "product 1" : 100,
    "product 2" : 100,
    "product 3" : 100,
    "product 4" : 100,
    "product 5" : 100
}
print("current stock: ",products)

change=input("Would you like to change stock amount? ")

if "yes" in change.lower():
    chosen_product=input("Which product would you like to change? ")
    products[chosen_product]=int(input("Would you like to add or subtract stock? "))
else:
    print("current stock: ",products)
```

Please see the change :

Once you get `chosen_product` form the user you can assign its value from `products` dictionary, Also, change the value to `int`.

**Edit**:

```
if "yes" in change.lower():
    chosen_product=input("Which product would you like to change? ")
    change_type=input("Would you like to add or subtract stock? ")
    value_add_or_sub=int(input("Value to be added or subtracted "))

if change_type =='add':
    products[chosen_product]= products[chosen_product] + value_add_or_sub

else:
    products[chosen_product]= products[chosen_product] - value_add_or_sub
```

Comment: I think OP wants an add/subtract option (`change_type`), and probably then the amount to be added/subtracted. This does work, though.

Comment: Sure, once we have clarification from OP I will update.

Comment: this makes sense, I was actually looking to add or subtract from the original 100 of whatever product the user chose, but assigning the value of chosen_product from the products dictionary was something I didn't know I could do. Will try it out and see if it works, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
products={
    "product 1" : 100,
    "product 2" : 100,
    "product 3" : 100,
    "product 4" : 100,
    "product 5" : 100
}
print("current stock: ",products)
change=input("Would you like to change stock amount? ")

while change.lower()=="yes":
    
    chosen_product=input("Which product would you like to change? ")
    operation=input("Would you like to add or subtract stock? ")
    
    if operation.lower() == "add":
        stock_change = int(input("How much stock would you like to add? "))
        products[chosen_product] += stock_change
        print(chosen_product, "stock increased by", stock_change)
    
    else:
        stock_change = int(input("How much stock would you like to subtract? "))
        products[chosen_product] -= stock_change
        print(chosen_product, "stock decreased by", stock_change)
    
    change=input("Would you like to change any other stock amount? ")

print("Current stock: ",products)
```

**Output:**

```
current stock:  {'product 1': 100, 'product 2': 100, 'product 3': 100, 'product 4': 100, 'product 5': 100}
Would you like to change stock amount? yes
Which product would you like to change? product 1
Would you like to add or subtract stock? add
How much stock would you like to add? 34
product 1 stock increased by 34
Would you like to change any other stock amount? yes
Which product would you like to change? product 3
Would you like to add or subtract stock? subtract
How much stock would you like to subtract? 78
product 3 stock decreased by 78
Would you like to change any other stock amount? no
Current stock:  {'product 1': 134, 'product 2': 100, 'product 3': 22, 'product 4': 100, 'product 5': 100}
```

**Further adds you can do in these code.!**

(1) To check if stock becomes `less than 0` than not do any operation.

(2) Assuming product user will enter will be in dictionary. you can add these check also [if product not present than print like.. this stock is not in your dictionary].

Comment: thank you! was gonna use a true/false type statement but I completely forgot how to ngl so I just went with whatever I knew, I'm gonna try update my code using these as references:)